Orthogonality problem in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Suppose $D f(a) \neq 0$ for some $a \in U$, and consider the vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
D f(a) u = \max \left\{ D f(a) h : \|h\|_{\mathbb{R}^n} = 1 \right\}.
$$
If $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $D f(a) v = 0$, show that $\langle v, u \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^n} = 0$.
My attempt: I believe the main idea is to show that $u$ is parallel to $\nabla f(a)$, which would make the result follow directly. However, I'm currently stuck on proving this parallel relationship.

By definition, since $f$ is differentiable, we have that:
$$
D_uf(a) = \nabla f(a)\cdot u = ||\nabla f(a)||\cdot ||u||\cos\alpha
$$
So the maximum will be reached when the cosine is equal to $1 \implies$ $\nabla f(a)$ and $u$ must be paralel. Furthermore, $u = \frac{\nabla f(a)}{||\nabla f(a)||}$

How do you conclude that $u=\frac{\nabla f(a)}{|\nabla f(a)|}$?

If you have a vector u parallel to another one, lets call it v, then u = kv, where k is a constant. If u is unitary, then u = v/||v||
